# Why get a response of 200 but not showing message body in the endpoint client with KAA

Tags: json, rest, api, kaa

I try with  Kaa Sandbox (curl command and UI) for using send notification with Json file.

**My problem is :**

when I using json file why not showing message body in the client endpoint (Notification demo (JAVA SDK) ?! , **While I receive 200 responses**.

**Hint:** sdk according to related schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right solution.

**1-** Make sure that your SDK related to schemaId

**2-** Make sure structure of your schema just given an message field:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Notification",
"namespace": "org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.example",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "message",
        "type": "string"
    }
]
```

}

**3-** and your json file :

```
{
  "message" : "Hello world!"
}
```

**4-** your curl command should be according to related schemaId and topicId and applic the tionId

For show to you:
This is my json file:
[image]

Then this is response in client:

[image]